# Error when attempting to decrypt/encrypt using RSA private/public Key

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa

I have 2 services where service A receives the public key from another service B, encrypts a string and then sends the encrypted string to service B which will use the private key to decrypt. Service B is written in python and this is how the key is generated:

```
def generateKeys(privateKeyFile, publicKeyFile, n=4096):
    (publicKey, privateKey) = rsa.newkeys(n)
    with open(publicKeyFile, 'wb') as p:
        p.write(publicKey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
    with open(privateKeyFile, 'wb') as p:
        p.write(privateKey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
```

This results in a privateKey.pem and a publicKey.pem in the following format:

```
Public Key:
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
.
.
.
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

Private Key:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
.
.
.
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

For testing purposes, I just copied the publicKey.pem file and am using that in my C++ code. I am posting a minimal code removing multiple null checks and stuff! Here is that:

```
int main()
{
    string devKey = "wh1plash";
    cout << devKey << "\n";
    string devKeyBase64 = base64_encode(devKey.c_str(), devKey.size());
    cout << "devKeyBase64 : " << devKeyBase64.c_str() << " size : " << devKeyBase64.size() << "\n";

    string publicKeyLocation = "/keys/publicKey.pem";
    FILE* file = fopen(publicKeyLocation.c_str(), "r");
    // Null Check here for file. Not shown here

    RSA *rsa = NULL;
    PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(file, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    // Null Check for RSA. Not shown here

    EVP_PKEY* evpPkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(evpPkey, rsa);
    // Null check for evpPkey. Not shown here

    fclose(file);
    
    // Create/initialize context
    EVP_PKEY_CTX* evpCtx;
    evpCtx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(evpPkey, NULL);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(evpCtx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    // Null check for evpCtx. Not shown here.

    EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(evpCtx);

    // Encryption
    size_t ciphertextLen;
    EVP_PKEY_encrypt(evpCtx, NULL, &ciphertextLen, (const unsigned char*)devKeyBase64.c_str(), devKeyBase64.size());
    cout << " Cipher Text Len : " << ciphertextLen << "\n";
    unsigned char* ciphertext = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(ciphertextLen);
    EVP_PKEY_encrypt(evpCtx, ciphertext, &ciphertextLen, (const unsigned char*)devKeyBase64.c_str(), devKeyBase64.size());

    string OutString;
    cout << " Cipher Text : " << ciphertext << "\n";
    OutString.assign((char*)ciphertext, ciphertextLen);

    cout << "Encrypted String: ||" << OutString.c_str() << "||";
    cout << "\nDone\n";

    // Release memory
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(evpCtx);
    // EVP_PKEY_free(evpPkey);
    // OPENSSL_free(ciphertext);
    return 0;
}
```

This does print a non-ascii string as the cypher text. Not sure if that is correct. Here is one example:

```
Cipher Text Len : 512
 Cipher Text : ���r�N�|�pۥ�7I��`�]k�n��"�ٕ�پ��������<��R�{�4:<�8g��W���u�UV7������SZ
�;bLbKo��!SY
            fx�0�̩#�>QG�� ��X���zNnm��.�\Y�D�Ս!�!�G��1�w�ϳ�h�ƅ�g����
Encrypted String: ||���r�N�|�pۥ�7I��`�]k�n��"�ٕ�پ��������<��R�{�4:<�8g��W���u�UV7������SZ
�;bLbKo��!SY
            fx�0�̩#�>QG�� ��X���zNnm��.�\Y�D�Ս!�!�G��1�w�ϳ�h�ƅ�g����||
Done
```

I tried decrypting this on the terminal by using the `openssl pkeyutl` but it fails unless I set the padding as none. And even then, it just results in gibberish non-ascii characters like above and not the original string (base64 encoded version). Any pointers on what I am doing wrong will be appreciated!

```
$ openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -in file.enc -inkey privateKey.pem -out out.txt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pkcs1
Public Key operation error
140501996771216:error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error:rsa_pk1.c:301:
140501996771216:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:rsa_eay.c:643:
```

Comment: In the Python code the name/link of the used library is missing, in the C code the implementation/link regarding `base64_encode()` is missing.

Comment: Your code does not contain an export of the ciphertext to *file.enc*. How do you create *file.enc*? Do you copy the data output on the console to the file? If so, this is the cause of the problem, as it corrupts the ciphertext. Either store the data directly in binary, or if you want to output it as string, use a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 or hex. Then you can create *file.enc* in a second step with the corresponding decoding (e.g. Base64: openssl enc -d -a -A...). For me deryption with the OpenSSL statment works, if this is considered.

Comment: @Topaco `import rsa` is the package. In C++ side, `base64_encode` is immaterial because that function just converts the plaint text to a base64 encoded version which is then encrypted by using the public key. And yes I was copying directly from the terminal. But let me try your way of writing it to a file.

Comment: How did you write to the file? I tried `BIO_dump_fp` to file and that does dump something to the file. But when I try to decrypt it, it is saying `data greater than mod len:rsa_eay.c:561` @Topaco

Comment: Use e.g. `FILE* write_ptr = fopen("<path to file>", "wb"); fwrite(ciphertext, ciphertextLen, 1, write_ptr);`

Comment: Also, could you give me the full command you use for the decryption part? I tried adding hexdump but it still is not giving me what I am expecting ( the base64 encoded plaintext that I encrypted)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254120/discussion-between-whiplash-and-topaco).

Comment: Do join the chat if you can @Topaco

Comment: @Topaco Got it working. I was using the wrong util in openssl. I should be using rsautl instead of pkeyutil

Comment: The ciphertext generated with the posted C code (if written to a file in binary as described) should work with both, i.e. with *pkeyutl* (as posted) and with the deprecated *rsautl*, which is the case for me (checked with OpenSSL v1.1.1 and v3.0.0).

Comment: It din't work with pkeyutl for me. Worked with rsautl though.

Comment: *rsautl* is deprecated (see [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-rsautl.html)), *pkeyutl* is the successor and is more capable. Since you encrypt in the C code with the old PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, decryption is possible with *both* commands. The fact that *pkeyutl* does not work for you indicates a local issue (OpenSSL version, different results of the C code etc). But without information about the OpenSSL version and a complete set of (non-productive) test data (key pair, plaintext, ciphertext) it is hard to identify the problem.